# Why Browsers do not resolve simple known issues?

Tags: css, browser-compatibility, css3

Why Browsers do not resolve simple known issues such as:

(in the context of CSS)

Do NOT start a class name with a number! This is only supported in Internet Explorer

and

Do NOT start an ID name with a number! It will not work in Mozilla/Firefox.

Comment: I don't think this is Browser/CSS specific.  The reasons for not fixing bugs of any kind are incredibly varied.

Comment: The correct behavior is what is in mozilla/firefox

Comment: Which browser? Do they have a bug-tracking system you could search and see if the issue is already logged and in-progress? Have you *asked* the teams of the browsers in question?

Comment: @Esailija hardly actually: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/global-attributes.html#the-id-attribute IE seems to be doing it right.

Answer (score 5):

These are not issues. This is the W3C standard.

Most good browsers try to follow standards as much as possible (Firefox, Chrome).

Some browser just doesn't care, or is trying to impose its own standard though (IE).

Comment: You have it backwards in this case: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/global-attributes.html#the-id-attribute